# Intersection between line and curve?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to find intersection between line(y=x) and a curve for instance y=tanh(x) I know they intersect on some points I don't know algebraically how to find that for example I tried

$tanh(x) = x$

$\dfrac{e^{x} - e^{-x}}{e^{x} + e^{x}} = x$

$\dfrac{e^{2x} - 1}{e^{2x} + 1} = x$

$ln(\dfrac{e^{2x} - 1}{e^{2x} + 1}) = ln(x)$

$ln({e^{2x} - 1}) - ln({e^{2x} + 1}) = ln(x)$

From this point I dont know how to expand it further to find the values of x where these two functions have same output.

Regards
Ahsan

Comment: why three point? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tanh%28x%29%3Dx

Comment: Pardon that was typo

Comment: you can't solve it algebraically. Usually for this problems you already have a guess, and prove it by deriving

Comment: $x=0$ is one solution

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner what about other solutions

Comment: i'm searching for other solutions

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner what is the algorithm in these situations to find the solutions

Comment: you can use the Newton method

Answer (score 0):

"I know they intersect on 3 points."

I'm not sure why you've made this assumption, but it's false. Assuming a real variable, they intersect only at the trivial point: $x = 0$.

Proof:

Notice: $\frac{d}{dx}\tanh(x) = 1 - \tanh^2(x)$, and of course $\frac{d}{dx}x = 1$.

Assume $x>0$, for the time being. You want $x-\tanh(x) = 0$, however:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x - \tanh(x)) = \tanh^2(x) > 0 \hspace{3mm} \forall x \in (0, \infty)$$

So the difference between the two functions is a strictly-monotonic increasing function on the positive reals. The same argument works on $x  < 0$.